# VS Code auto imports not using absolute paths and not indented

Tags: visual-studio-code, import, auto, auto-import

[image]

I'm using Typescript with SvelteKit

When I type something that can be auto imported, as seen in the above GIF, the auto import doesn't keep things at the same indent level. I also need absolute paths:

`/src/...`

not

`src/...`

The VS code setting for this is called TypeScript > Suggest: Auto Imports

It's a minor inconvenience but I am a programmer and this is making me work harder than I ought to. /s

Answer (score 7):

##### While I can't help with the exact solution,

##### I can propose a workaround that will save you some work.

---

### Import Path:

- Open the settings dialog (`CTRL+,`)
- Search for `typescript import module specifier`
- Make sure you select the *TypeScript* one, there's also one for JavaScript
- Switch it from `shortest` to `relative`

[image]

##### Now when you auto-import, a relative path will be used which compiles correctly.

---

### Indentation:

##### You can use `ALT+SHIFT+F` to format the entire file which will fix that as well.

Comment: This is what I was looking for !!! After so much pain updating manually each import in my React Native project , thank you !

Answer (score 3):

In your `settings.json` file add the following:

> "javascript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier": "relative",
> "typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier": "relative"